# Combine 2 solutions for making perfect proportional buttons and working on mac firefox

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[code](http://%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/sm40exqz/7/)Actually in my code first segment , buttons are working fine on mac firefox, but they are not proportional. That's why i modified them . they are proportional as i want but they are not working on mac firefox. I have so many pages and every pages using button but redirect to other pages. i need solution for all.

Comment: Please share your code / your approaches what you have done so far, etc. Otherwise its hard to help here.

Comment: @Stretau , here is the code.. sorry i forget to attach.. https://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/sm40exqz/7/

Answer (score 0):

Why are are using a inside button or vice versa. Though I don't use bootstrap but you can add d-flex and text-center class to btn-group.

```
<div class='btn-group d-flex text-center'>
      <a href="/p/89" class="col btn-change" style="color: white;">Portrait</a>
      <a href="/p/89" class="col btn-change" style="color: white;">Landscape</a>
      <a href="/p/89" class="col btn-change" style="color: white;">square</a>
 </div>
```